# Mouse cursor freezes randomly with Intel GMA 950

Tags: 10.10, mouse, intel-graphics, freeze

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 its installed using Wubi, dual boot with Windows.
It's fresh install.

Randomly mouse cursor freezes and can't click anything on the screen. I can move mouse but can't click.

"It causes when select a text something" So I'm using keyboard to to reboot system. 
Then it back to normal after reboot. Tried with unplugging-plugging mouse don't work.

PC: Asus laptop with Intel GMA 950 graphic card. A4 tech optical mouse.
Ubuntu 10.10 completely updated and upgraded.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Sounds like a compiz effects problem to me.  Try turning off all the effects and such that you can in System->Preferences->CompizConfig

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the [X-Updates PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) to your software sources.

To do so you only need to enter

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

in a Terminal window. After doing that you'll need to check for software updates.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem on an Acer laptop, and read somewhere that removing and reinserting the mouse driver can help. It worked for me so later i added the command to the end of the boot-process (around *rcX.d S99* ).

`sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse`